# How can I get information from a select with angularjs and ionic1?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-model

How can I get information from a select with angularjs and ionic1?

I'm trying to get the information from a JSON and put in the "select", until that part I got to do. But when I select the information from this "select" and try to get the id and the name that is in the "select", it is not showing.

My html -> igreja.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Igrejas">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
     <form ng-submit="realizarLogin()">
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <ion-item class="item-input item-select--full">
          <div class="input-label">
            Selecione a sua igreja
          </div>
          <select ng-model="login" ng-options="y.Nome for (x,y) in igrejaEscolhida">
          </select>
          <h1> test: {{login.Nome}}</h1>
          <h1> id: {{login.Id}} </h1>
        </ion-item> 

        <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My routes.js

```
.state('app.igrejas', {
    url: '/igrejas',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/igrejas.html',
        controller: 'igrejasController'
      }
    }
  })
```

My controller.js

```
.controller('igrejasController', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $state, $rootScope, $http, $sce) {



  $http.get(linkIgrejas).then(function(data){

    $scope.igrejaEscolhida = data.data;

    console.log($scope.igrejaEscolhida);

    $scope.igrejaEscolhida.forEach(function(element, index, array){
      element.Id = element.Id;
      element.Nome = element.Nome;
      console.log(element.Id);
      console.log(element.Nome);
    })

  })

  $rootScope.login = {};

  $scope.realizarLogin = function() {


    var dadosDoLogin = {
      params : {
        nome: $rootScope.login.nome
      }
    }

    $scope.selectUpdated = function(optionSelected) {

      console.log('Updated');
      console.log(optionSelected);

    };

    console.log($scope.selectUpdated);

    $scope.loginF.Nome;
    $scope.loginF.Id;

    console.log($scope.loginF.Nome);
    console.log($scope.loginF.Id);


     $rootScope.teste = $rootScope.login.nome;
     $scope.nomeIgreja = $rootScope.login.nome;
     $scope.idIgreja = $rootScope.login.Id;

     $rootScope.login.Id;

      console.log($scope.nomeIgreja);
      console.log($scope.idIgreja);



  };
})
```

Could someone help me or show me what I'm doing wrong in the "select"?

Comment: it looks like `$scope.igrejaEscolhida` is an array but you are using `(x,y) in igrejaEscolhida` which is the syntax for objects.  try `ng-options="y as y.Nome for y in igrejaEscolhida"` instead.

Comment: can you put a sample from `$scope.igrejaEscolhida`

Comment: I am not able to get what was selected in the select in my controller, I made the change that you say is working the same before, but how can I get the name and id in my controller? I've tried doing something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select_object_y @Claies

Comment: I added in my controller the $scope.igrejaEscolhida and tested, but I need to know the igrejaEscolhida what name and id that was selected @Abdoutelb

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking at this point.  you have a `$scope.selectUpdated` function that doesn't appear to be used, and you have a button on your page that has no handler on it. (e.g. `ng-click`).  How else were you expecting to use the dropdown value in the controller?

Comment: I do it this way: first I try to get what is coming from the front and then play in console.log to test. I tried to do a select this way: <select ng-model="login.nome" ng-change="selectUpdated(optionSelected)">
    <option ng-repeat="igrejaEscolhidas in igrejaEscolhida" value="igrejaEscolhidas.Nome">
        {‌{ igrejaEscolhidas.Nome }}
    </option>
</select>


$scope.selectUpdated = function(optionSelected) {
    console.log('Updated');
    console.log(optionSelected);
}; But it does not work. @Claies

Comment: @Lucas in the select you should make the option `option ng-repeat="igrejaEscolhidas in igrejaEscolhida" value="igrejaEscolhidas.I'd"> {‌{ igrejaEscolhidas.Nome }} </option> `.  Take the I'd inside value property and so if you doing ng-options you should make  `<select ng-model="login" ng-options="y.Name for y.Id in igrejaEscolhida">
          </select>`

Comment: Try to wrap your input's scope vars in an object: `<select ng-model="wrobj.login" ng-options="y.Nome for (x,y) in igrejaEscolhida">
          </select>`

Comment: Hi @Abdoutelb , I tried to do so: <select ng-model="login.nome"> <option ng-repeat="igrejaEscolhidas in igrejaEscolhida" value="igrejaEscolhidas.Nome">  but when I prove this is coming just the igrejaEscolhidas.Nome in console, I need to get my controller in the IgrejaEscolhidas.Nome and IgrejaEscolhidas.Id

Comment: Hi @neptune I tried to change the way to do the select I did a bit like what I say, but I would like to get the ID and the name of the igrejaEscolhidas in the controller.js, I'm getting the two together, you know if there's anybody like me Catch him apart?

Comment: Many thanks for the help I changed and some things and I did like this: <select ng-model="login.igreja" ng-options="igreja.Id as igreja.Nome for igreja in igrejaEscolhida"> <option value="">Selecione uma Igreja</option> </select> And it's working for me.  Thanks a lot for the help. @neptune

Comment: Many thanks for the help I changed and some things and I did like this: <select ng-model="login.igreja" ng-options="igreja.Id as igreja.Nome for igreja in igrejaEscolhida"> <option value="">Selecione uma Igreja</option> </select> And it's working for me. Thanks a lot for the help. @Claies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my Igrejas.html and controller.js

Igrejas.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Igrejas">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
     <form ng-submit="realizarLogin()">
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <ion-item class="item-input item-select--full">
          <div class="input-label">
            Selecione a sua igreja
          </div>
          <select ng-model="login.nome">
                  <option ng-repeat="igrejaEscolhidas in igrejaEscolhida">
                   {{ igrejaEscolhidas.Nome }}
                   {{ igrejaEscolhidas.Id }}
                  </option>
          </select>
        </ion-item> 

        <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My controller.js

```
.controller('igrejasController', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $state, $rootScope, $http, $sce) {



  $http.get(linkIgrejas).then(function(data){

    $scope.igrejaEscolhida = data.data;

    console.log($scope.igrejaEscolhida);

    $scope.igrejaEscolhida.forEach(function(element, index, array){
      element.Id = element.Id;
      element.Nome = element.Nome;
      console.log(element.Id);
      console.log(element.Nome);
    })

  })

  $rootScope.login = {};

  $scope.realizarLogin = function() {


     $rootScope.teste = $rootScope.login.nome;

    console.log($rootScope.teste);




  };
})
```

When I tested this way I managed to get the id and name, but they are together like this in this print, I need to get them separated, how do they separate them in angularjs?

My print :

http://prntscr.com/fhg4py

Or someone knows how I can get the id and separate name, being that I have this id and that name will come from the same select? I got them together.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the value itself to represent The id

```
<option ng-repeat="igrejaEscolhidas in igrejaEscolhida" value="{{ igrejaEscolhidas.Id }}">
                   {{ igrejaEscolhidas.Nome  }}
                  </option>
```

then the ng-model with the `select` will take the Id from the value of the selected option.

Comment: Many thanks for the help I changed and some things and I did like this: <select ng-model="login.igreja" ng-options="igreja.Id as igreja.Nome  for igreja in igrejaEscolhida">
            <option value="">Selecione uma Igreja</option>
          </select>  And it's working for me. @Abdoutelb

Comment: @LucasSantos you can append style the the default option`<option value="" style="display:none">Selecione uma Igreja</option>`